# Beginner: Can't Order my WHERE Statements Properly with Subselect MIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

For some reason, I am unable to get this query to return anything.

```
SELECT 
     film.title, 
     film.length 
FROM moviedb.film, moviedb.`language` 
WHERE film.length=(SELECT 
                         MIN(length) 
                   FROM moviedb.film) 
AND film.language_id=`language`.language_id 
AND `language`.`name`='French' 
AND film.rating='R';
```

So, I am wanting to return two columns with 1 row...the shortest french movie with an 'R' rating. Am I missing something here? I've been scratching my head for an hour.

Comment: In your subquery you need to specify which language movies min length you want ? Currently it is fetching whichever min length it has probably that will be for other language film and thats why it is not matching any record. And you can use `JOIN `

Comment: @Napoleon Can you please provide a dummy table here that would be helpful.

Comment: i'm trying to get this query to return the shortest french film that is rated R. do i have to add more to the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify language and rating in the sub-query too, to get the shortest film of those:

```
SELECT 
     film.title, 
     film.length 
FROM moviedb.film f1 JOIN moviedb.`language`
     ON  film.language_id = `language`.language_id 
WHERE film.length = (SELECT MIN(length) 
                     FROM moviedb.film f2
                     WHERE f1.language_id = f2.language_id
                       AND f1.rating = f2.rating) 
AND `language`.`name`='French' 
AND film.rating='R';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using old-style/implicit `JOIN` syntax. See in this **[article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)** if why. So, I converted your query into explicit `JOIN`. Try this query:

```
SELECT 
     A.title, 
     A.length 
FROM film A 
INNER JOIN language B ON A.language_id=B.language_id 
WHERE A.length=(SELECT MIN(length) FROM film) 
AND B.name`='French' 
AND A.rating='R';
```

Comment: i'm afraid this didnt do the trick. When i remove the MIN subselect and run it as its own query, it works. the whole query also works if i remove the MIN statement, so i believe i am doing something wrong with the MIN statement? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a big flaw (that was pointed out by other answers too): the inner query selects the smallest movie length from the entire table. The outer query tries to find a movie that has some properties (rating, language) and the length equal to the minimum length selected by the inner query. It doesn't produce any result just because the shortest movie doesn't match the properties you search for (rating, language).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449288/4265352) tries to fix your query and it probably works. I didn't test it, I don't like sub-queries when they are not needed.

Try this query:

```
SELECT sf.title, sf.length 
FROM moviedb.`language` l
    INNER JOIN moviedb.film sf               # "sf" from "shortest film"
      ON sf.language_id = l.language_id
    LEFT JOIN moviedb.film es                # "es" from "even shorter"
      ON es.rating = sf.rating AND es.language_id = sf.language_id
      AND es.length < sf.length              # "es" is shorter than "sf"
WHERE l.`name` = 'French' AND film.rating = 'R'
  AND es.length IS NULL                      # there is no "even shorter" film
```

#### How it works

It joins the table `languages` (to select only the French films) with `film` (aliased as `sf`) and again with `film` (aliased as `es`). The first join is on `language_id`. Together with the `WHERE` condition `l.name = 'French'` this ensures it will select only French films.

Each pair (language, film) created by the `INNER JOIN` is paired by the `LEFT JOIN` with all the rows from `es` that have the same rating and language AND have shorter length (`es.length < sf.length`). Because of the `LEFT JOIN`, all the rows from the left side table will appear in the joined set. Here, the left side is a join and that means all the pairs (`l`, `sf`) produced by the `INNER JOIN` will appear in the set produced by the `LEFT JOIN`. When a matching row from `es` cannot be found (because the row selected from `sf` has the smallest value for `length`), a row full of `NULL`s will be used instead.

The `WHERE` conditions on language and rating keeps only the pairs we need (language: 'French', rating: 'R'). The last condition (`es.length IS NULL`) keeps only the pairs that have `NULL`s in the fields of `es` (because there is no "even shorter" film than the one selected from `sf`).

The `SELECT` clause gets only the columns we need. You can use tables `l` and `sf` there. The values selected from `es` are always `NULL`.

#### Remarks about the performance

No matter what query you use, in order to make it as fast as possible, the table(s) involved need to have indexes on the column(s) that are used for search and comparison (i.e. the columns that appear in the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses).

For this query, the columns are `film.language_id`, `film.rating` and `film.length`. Also `language.language_id` but it probably is a `PK` (already indexed).